# chefspec: test linux kernel version number

Tags: ruby, linux, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

How do I write a test on Linux system meets minimum kernel version of 2.6.20 or greater inside the following file?

> spec/unit.recipes/default_spec.rb

Answer (score 1):

ChefSpec isn't used for things like this, it doesn't know anything about actual systems. It just runs your recipe code in an abstract no-op-y kind of way. Most Chef users neither need nor should use ChefSpec, it's for stupidly complex cookbooks mostly, like the kind released to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an integration testing tool like test kitchen for that since chefspec doesn't run on a actual machine where as kitchen tests does. You can use either serverspec or inspec as your testing framework. Refer https://docs.chef.io/kitchen.html